# Get attribute table from WMS GeoServer in OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers, wms, getfeatureinfo

I have WMS so I can easily display it in the map, but I want to get the attribute table of the layer from WMS. All solutions I found are about getFeatureInfo which is giving properties when clicking on a place on the map. Is there a way to get the attribute table of a layer using WMS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the actual data then you need to use a WFS request rather than a WMS request.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to get the attribute table of a layer using WMS?

No, a WMS layer doesn't have any attributes. It is an image (mostly) representation of a set of data. The GetFeatureInfo request gives access to the underlying data.